# invalidValueError : setCenter : not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral Object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to google map `api v3`. I already establish a decent google map with 2 marker but when I use `google.maps.latlngBounds`, it return me an **error**

`invalidValueError : setCenter : not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral Object`.

How can I fix this? 
I just want to centre my map around these markers.

```
function initialize() {

          var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
          var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.573688, 132.567212);

        var mapOptions = {
          center: myLatlng,
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        try {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng
        });

        var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng2
        });

        trackerMarkerArray.push(marker);
        trackerMarkerArray.push(marker2);

        var latlngbound = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
        for (var i = 0; i<trackerMarkerArray.length; i++){
            trackerMarkerArray[i].setMap(map);

            latlngbound.extend(trackerMarkerArray[i].position);
        }




        //render new map and center around group of marker
        map.setCenter(latlngbound);
        map.fitBounds(latlngbound);


        } catch (err){
            alert(err);
        }


      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 3):

To "fit" the map to a set of markers added to a [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) object use map.fitBounds(bounds), not map.setCenter().

[google.maps.Map documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)

Comment: Then the bounds your code is creating has a problem (or the data you are adding to it results in a bounds that covers the whole world).  But using the code you posted works for me [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y29dW/) (once I fix the obvious javascript errors and remove invalid map.setCenter(bounds) call)

Answer (score 1):

```
    map.setCenter(latlngbound);
```

[map.setCenter takes a LatLng as a parameter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map), you're passing a LatLngBounds, I think you want to do it like this:

```
    map.setCenter(latlngbound.getCenter());
```

Comment: ok, i get the result but the map zoom out until the end of the line..... can u suggest me what shoud i do with the map. the zoom out part